# How to prevent errors during include if file not exist (without @)

Tags: php

Hi guys could you help me with next.

I have next code

> index.php

```
set_include_path(get_include_path()
            .PATH_SEPARATOR.'application/controllers'
            .PATH_SEPARATOR.'application/models'
            .PATH_SEPARATOR.'application/views');
spl_autoload_register();
$front = new Controller;
$front->route();
```

> Controller.php

```
public function route(){
    if(class_exists($this->getController())){...}......
```

I have one way. Insted of using `spl_autoload_register();` I can write

```
function __autoload($classname) {
 @include_once $classname.'.php';
}
```

But according php documentation, I want to use spl_autoload_register...
If you need full code, I'll be glad to demonstrate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Question in header - How to prevent errors during include if file not exist

Comment: Your task is quite impossible. If you are autoloading a class that doesn't exist, just preventing the error from trying to include that file won't solve your problem, because you're trying to use a class that PHP doesn't know about.

Comment: You're right. Probably, my answer is how to bind get_include_path and file_exists.....

Comment: I made it next way:

    $arr = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR,get_include_path());
    foreach ($arr as $val){
  if(file_exists($val.'/'.$classname.'.php')){
   include_once $classname.'.php';
   break;
  }
 }

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use file_exists, I suppose...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
if( file_exists( 'path/to/' . $classname / '.php' ) )
{
  include_once( $classname.'.php' );
}
```

Why are you autoloading classes that don't exist?

You could also try this:

```
if( !include_once( $classname.'.php' ) )
{
  //throw error, or do something... or nothing
  throw new Exception( "Autoload for $classname failed. Bad path." );
}
```

Comment: Did you see my question? Why are you loading classes that don't exist? That's really the way to stop errors from being thrown lol. Also, why don't you know the path?

Comment: I'm creating my own framework. I'm making routing throught url. 
For example: http://localhost/admin/index
It means, automatically will open function index of class "admin".
I made it succesfully.
But now, I'm working with protection.
For example if try to go to http://localhost/anything/index, it will generate error, because I don't have class "anything"

Comment: good trial, but it still generate error. Here is should be used try catche operator

Comment: Yes that was just a psuedo code example. You'd want to try/catch if throwing exceptions. So your concern is that if you kept all of your class files in one directory, that you'll have some kind of security breach? Like someone will execute a class file without permission, or in the wrong part of your framework?

Comment: I made it pretty cool! The classes that shouldn't be executed aren't implementet empty interface "IController". And after I'm checking implementation by next code - if(!$rc->implementsInterface('IController')){header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");}

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that I use (I hope it will give you an idea):

```
<?php
Class ClassAutoloader {

  function __construct() {
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
  }

  private function loader($className) {

    $classPath = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if(file_exists( $classPath.strtolower($className).'.php' )) {
      include $classPath.strtolower($className).'.php' ;
    } else if(file_exists( $classPath.$className.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.strtolower($className).'.php' )) {
      include $classPath.$className.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.strtolower($className).'.php';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off errors with

```
 <?PHP 
 error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING)
 ?>
```

Comment: not good idea too, I want to somehow make checking if file_exists, but I can't use that function because path is in get_include_path()